# query mysql should return only unbooked

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate

i got 3 tables

Lakes - id,name,lat,lon

Pegs  - id, pegNumber, pegName,lake_id

Reservations- id, start_day,end_day , peg_id

Iam trying wrote the query who return me the list unbooked pegs on lake on one day or between two dates. I wrote that query but they return me only already booked.

```
SELECT l.name,p.id,p.peg_number,r.start_day,r.end_day     
FROM reservations r 
left join pegs  p on r.peg_id = p.id 
left join lakes l on p.lake_id = l.id
WHERE r.start_day is not null 
order by l.name
```

Anyone can help me with that ?

Comment: if you provide a [mre] we can better help you

Comment: for example i wanna know which pegs are not booked on 2021-11-15.  My query return me the list only already booked i need to hmm like reverse the result

Comment: a ]mre] should show data as well a create table and a dbfiddle could also help